# Partial Search with Mongodb in Rails application with Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am trying to implement the Elasticsearch for partial search on my fields. I have created a Rails application using Mongodb for database. I have implemented the Elasticsearch and am able to search the full-text successfully. However I am willing to make changes for partial search.

Following the setting what I have in my application:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'mongoid', '~> 6.0'
gem 'mongoid-elasticsearch'
```

app/models/post.rb

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Elasticsearch

  elasticsearch!({
            index_name: 'post_indexes',
             prefix_name: false,
             index_options: {
              filter:{
                autocomplete_filter:{
                  type: "edge_ngram",
                  min_gram: 3,
                  max_gram: 20
                }
               },
               analyzer:{
                   autocomplete:{
                     type: "custom",
                     tokenizer: "standard",
                     filter: [
                       "lowercase",
                       "autocomplete_filter"
                     ]
                 }
               }
             },
             index_mappings: {
               posts:{
                 properties:{
                   title:    { type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed },
                   content:  { type: 'string' }
                 }
               }
             },
             wrapper: :load
           })

  field :title, type: String
  field :content, type: String
end
```

Here is the [link](https://medium.com/@xoor/indexing-mongodb-with-elasticsearch-2c428b676343) I am following.

### Update 1

Here is what I tried in mappings:

```
title:    { type: 'string', index: :not_analyzed, analyzer: "autocomplete" },
```

But still I don't get the O/P. I have also refreshed the index using `Post.es.index.refresh`

### Update 2

Here is what I have tried to solve error:

`Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":"MapperParsingException[mapping [post]]; nested: MapperParsingException[Analyzer [autocomplete] not found for field [title]]; ","status":400}`

```
elasticsearch!({
                   index_name: 'mongo_post_indexes',
                   prefix_name: false,
                   index_options: {
                     settings: {
                       index:{
                         analysis:{
                           filter:{
                             autocomplete_filter:{
                               type: "ngram",
                               min_gram: 1,
                               max_gram: 20
                             }
                           },
                           analyzer:{
                             autocomplete:{
                               type: "custom",
                               tokenizer: "standard",
                               filter: [
                                  "lowercase",
                                  "autocomplete_filter"
                                ]
                             }
                           }
                         }
                       }
                     },
                     mappings: {
                      "posts" => {
                        properties: {
                          title: {type: 'text', boost: 10, analyzer: 'autocomplete'},
                          tags: {type: 'string', analyzer: 'autocomplete'}
                        }
                      }
                    }
                   },
                   wrapper: :load
                 })
```

Comment: what problem you are facing ?

Comment: If I enter "tes" to search I should get results that contains "Tesla" also.

Comment: Can you provide your search query? also which version of ES u are using?

Comment: Can you modify the mapping to `title:    { type: 'string', index: :analyzed, analyzer: "autocomplete" }` and as its a breaking change, you need to create a new index after  you update the mapping of index.

Comment: Tried the changes you suggested and got following O/P while creating the index:  ```Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":"MapperParsingException[mapping [post]]; nested: MapperParsingException[Analyzer [autocomplete] not found for field [title]]; ","status":400}```

Comment: can you provide the O/P of `_mapping` api ?

Comment: error means `autocomplete` analyzer is not found in your ES mapping.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal Thanks for guiding me with the error. I have updated the question with heading "Update 2". Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189795/discussion-between-amit-khandelwal-and-vishal).

Comment: were u able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal I had to replace the ```mongoid-elasticsearch``` gem with ```searchkick``` gem.

Answer (score 0):

As OP, posted in the comment, If the index contains `Tesla`, then searching for `tes`, should give the result.

One thing I noticed in your index mapping is `title` field is not using any analyzer and `content` field also doesn't use the custom analyzer which you created for autocomplete functionality, so by default, it would use the `standard` analyzer.

Can you please check the tokens generated for these 2 fields using the `_analyze` api https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html and let me know the O/P of it.

If it doesn't generate the tokens like below for `Tesla`, then for your query assuming you are using `match` or `term` query (Asked in question which query OP is using) :-

> tes , tesl , tesla

Let me know if you have any questions.

Edit :- Had a chat with OP and found he was not forming proper query for autocomplete. Below is the snippet from chat which should resolve the issue.

> your query is not returning result b/c u are using
>   Post.es.search("Tes") for autocomplete search while "Post" doesn't
>   contain the autocomplete analyzer, you should instead use
>   **Posts.es.search("Tes")** (notice `s` in post) for autocomplete search

Comment: Here is my search query: ```Post.es.search('tes').raw_response``` . The version of my Elasticsearch is: 1.7.2.

Comment: Also I have updated the question with "Update 1" heading. can you please have a look at it?

Comment: Can you provide the O/P of `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html` ?